# Excel Formula to show value in a specific cell after same interval

Tags: excel

[image]

I am trying to show the value of B4 to D33 and when I drag it down it shows the value of B13 to D34 and so on with the same interval and pattern. I found a [help article](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3661-excel-return-value-every-nth-row.html) with the OFFSET function, tried it but it seems to be not working in my case. Any suggestion?

Regards

Comment: What output do you expect and what formula try yet? Show us your effort.

Answer (score 2):

A tricky one. It looks like you want to get Week1 value from datasets 1, 2 or 3, depending of which row.

References in Excel do not work the way you want. When draging fórmulas they will always increase reference by 1 column or 1 row. So you need to be tricky here.

One approach would be this:

[image]

My formula in cell D33 is:

```
=VLOOKUP($A$30;CHOOSE(MID(A33;5;99);$A$4:$B$8;$A$13:$B$17;$A$22:$B$26);2;FALSE)
```

Comment: @firefox yes you got my problem right, whenever I drag it down it increases the row by 1. The help article I cited above seems to be working while dragging when rows are adjacent but not in my case. Moreover, I copied and pasted your formula but it seems to be not working either. Besides, it seems complicated and I am not very proficient at Excel, perhaps I should go for the simple = references, one by one :(

Comment: Notice my Excel setup needs `;` as delimiter in functions, but other setups require commas, so sometimes copying and pasting does not work because of that. Also, you'll need to translate the functions to whatever language setupf your Excel is.